# Create a boolean from a string

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a boolean from an Edit Text field.

I've already converted it into a string but need to make a boolean from the answer. I want to assign the correct answer as 1 and 2 as the wrong answer. If you can give me a tip how to make sure they enter only 1 or 2 that would be great!

This is what i have so far:

```
public void EnterAnswer(Editable insertAnswer) {
 EditText enterAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_question_six);
 String answer = enterAnswer.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I would completely rewrite your question to: "I have `String answer = "green";` How can I convert that string to a boolean?". Note that you would have to explain how the string should be matched with a boolean though.

Comment: Dina, are you trying to do this is Android?

Comment: The only two real-world use cases I can think of for something like this are if you want the user to select between multiple options (in which case radio buttons would be a much better choice), or the user is entering a password (in which case storing it in plain text in the source code is almost certainly not what you want to be doing, unless this is just a throwaway type hobby project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, using an EditText, there is really no way of specifying the values a user can input. Best you can do is to use the `input type` attribute by setting the input type to "number" as shown below. This way, a user would only be able to input numbers.

```
android:inputType="number"
```

You can also use the setError() method of the EditText to display an error if the user inputs a value that is neither 0 nor 1. This is illustrated below:

```
if(!(editText.getText().toString().equals("0") || editText.getText().toString().equals("1"))){

     editText.setError("Wrong input, you can only input 0 or 1");

    }
```

Follow this procedure:

- Get the text from your textview
- Check whether the text is one or two
- assign a value to your boolean variable based on the result above.

**Illustration:**

```
public boolean EnterAnswer(Editable answerView){
   boolean result = false;

   String answer = answerView.getText().toString().trim();

   if(answer.equals("1")){
       result = true;
     }

   return result;
   }
```

Following the logic above, the method will only return true if the answer (from the EditText) is one.

I hope this helps... Merry coding!

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work but then when i get to calculate the score and produce the final  score from the whole quiz it crashes :-(

Comment: @dinadavis, I just (re)-tested this code and it works perfectly. There may be a totally unrelated reason why your app is crashing. Check/log the exact error your app is giving off and reply as a comment. Let's help you debug. ;-)

Comment: @dinadavis, you can mark this as the correct answer if it helped. :-)

Comment: this was very helpful, only I had to use if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))